# how to delete the empty value option in $form->select

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.2

when i need to use select form i see the first value is empty..but i dont need this empty value option ..how to do this..thanks

```
 <?php
    $options = array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female');
    echo $this->Form->select('gender', $options)
    ?>
```

Will output:

```
<select name="data[User][gender]" id="UserGender">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="M">Male</option>
<option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: **answer**

     $options = array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female',array('empty'=>false));

Comment: I haven't tested your code in CakePHP 1.3.x, but in the most recent version (CakePHP 2.0), doing that just adds a 3rd option that's empty. (and it doesn't look like it should work in any version since you're setting one of the select `<option>`s to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cake 2.x, you can just add the `'empty'=>false` like this (tested and works):

```
<?php
$options = array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female');
echo $this->Form->select('gender', $options, array('empty'=>false));
?>
```

In CakePHP 1.3.x (per [this page in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1430/select)) you might have to add an additional `null` like this:

```
<?php
$options = array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female');
echo $this->Form->select('gender', $options, null, array('empty'=>false));
?>
```